# PHP: Foreach echo not showing anything

Tags: arrays, list, session, foreach, shopping-cart

**EDIT**

Now I can output the current product, but every time the form adds another item it gets overriden. I want to make the list incremental like this:

```
 1. Banana 3 Units, Price 350 CRC
2. Yougurt 4 Units Price 2000 CRC
3. etc etc
4. etc
```

The current output only shows the last added item.

This is the script:

```
<?php

session_start();

//Getting the list
$list= $_SESSION['list'];


//stock
$products = array(

      'Pineaple' => 500, 'Banana' => 50, 'Mango' => 150, 
      'Milk' => 500, 'Coffe' => 1200, 'Butter' => 300,
      'Bread' => 450, 'Juice' => 780, 'Peanuts' => 800,
      'Yogurt' => 450, 'Beer' => 550, 'Wine' => 2500,
  );

//Saving the stuff
$_SESSION['list'] = array(
    'item' => ($_POST['product']), 
    'quantity' => ($_POST['quantity']),
    'code' => ($_POST['code']),
);

//price
$price = $products[($_SESSION['list']['item'])] * $_SESSION['list']['quantity'];

$_SESSION['list']['price'] = $price;


//listing
echo  "<b>SHOPPIGN LIST</b></br>";

foreach($_SESSION as $key => $item) 
{
    echo $key[''], '. ', $item['item'], ' ', $item['quantity'], ' units: ', $item['price'];
}

//Recycling list
 $_SESSION['list'] = $list;

echo "</br> <a href='index.html'>Return to index</a> </br>";


//Printing session
var_dump($_SESSION);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is your issue.

```
$_SESSION['list'] = array('price' => $price,);
```

You're setting the variable you're trying to iterate across to be an array with a single entry in it, not to mention the fact that `$price` isn't going to be a nested array, which is why trying to get `item['key']` is failing (as in `'price'` will be your key and `$price` will be your item in your foreach).

EDIT:

I believe, from a second quick glance you're actually intending to do this:

```
$_SESSION['list']['price'] = $price;
```

correct me if I'm wrong.

EDIT 2:

Actually, looking again, I'm not quite sure I understand your structure for your `$_SESSION['list']` variable. It looks like you want something like:

```
(('item' => 'Banana', 'quantity' => 1...), ('item' => 'Apple', 'quantity' => 2...))
```

but what you have (from the fact you reference `$_SESSION['list']['item']`) is only:

```
('item' => 'Banana', 'quantity' => 1...)
```

you actually have multiple problems here. First try and deal with the bad structure of `$_SESSION['list']` then try and deal with the foreach loop.

EDIT 3:

I still don't think you're quite understanding what I mean, so I'm just going to fix the code to be what I'm pretty sure you're looking for...

I'm pretty sure what you're going for looks something like this:

```
<?php

session_start();
$products = array(
      'Pineaple' => 500, 'Banana' => 50, 'Mango' => 150, 
      'Milk' => 500, 'Coffe' => 1200, 'Butter' => 300,
      'Bread' => 450, 'Juice' => 780, 'Peanuts' => 800,
      'Yogurt' => 450, 'Beer' => 550, 'Wine' => 2500,
);

if(!array_key_exists('list', $_SESSION)){
  $_SESSION['list'] = array();
}

$price = $products[$_POST['product']] * $_POST['quantity'];
array_push($_SESSION['list'],
           array(
             'item' => $_POST['product'], 
             'quantity' => $_POST['quantity'],
             'code' => $_POST['code'],
             'price' => $price,
          ));    

echo  "<b>SHOPPING LIST</b></br>";    
foreach($_SESSION['list'] as $key => $item) {
    echo $key+1, '. ', $item['item'], ' ', $item['quantity'], ' units: ', $item['price'];
}

echo "</br> <a href='index.html'>Return to index</a> </br>";

?>
```

Comment: Thanks photoionized,

But now I'm getting a weird output (Y appear to be from Yogurt):

item. Y Y unitsYquantity. 4 4 units4code. d d unitsdprice. units

Comment: photoioized, Gabriel will still have the problem of trying to iterate an $item[] array in the foreach() that doesn't exist.

Comment: I think perhaps, Gabriel, use photoiodized change, but also alter your foreach() to just iterate over $_SESSION and not $_SESSION['list']

Comment: @iandouglas: nope, that's going to give weird keys, the issue is more complicated than just the loop, it looks like funny things are trying to be done with `$_SESSION['list']`, see second edit.

Comment: Hey guys, now is looking much better, but the array keeps being overriden by the last added product. Please check the EDITED script above.

Comment: @Gabriel: see my 3rd Edit above. I'm pretty sure this is the behavior you're describing you actually want.

Comment: Thanks, sweet! Is working 100%, just one last question. What to do when the $_POST['product'] is different from the products array? I´m getting undefined Index messages, and it´s being added to the array!
check the screenshot:
http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/7743/20110430021940.jpg

Comment: @Gabriel: you use the same `array_key_exists` syntax to check if the value in `$_POST['product']` exists in the products array before using it, if it doesn't respond to the user with some sort of "Invalid product" message. That's pretty simple server-side form validation.

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding your $_SESSION['list'] value with just the calculated price, so when you iterate through $_SESSION['list'], the only thing you have in $item is a scalar value of the calculated subtotal, not the array you hope for under your 'saving the stuff' comment.

If you're simply trying to print out the array of product/quantity/code/price this should work:

```
<?php

session_start() ;

//Stock
$products = array(
    'Pineaple' => 500, 'Banana' => 50, 'Mango' => 150, 
    'Milk' => 500, 'Coffe' => 1200, 'Butter' => 300,
    'Bread' => 450, 'Juice' => 780, 'Peanuts' => 800,
    'Yogurt' => 450, 'Beer' => 550, 'Wine' => 2500,
    );  

$_POST['product'] = 'Banana' ;
$_POST['quantity'] = 50 ;
$_POST['code'] = "unknown" ;

//Saving the stuff
$_SESSION['list'] = array(
    'item' => $_POST['product'],
    'quantity' => $_POST['quantity'],
    'code' => $_POST['code'],
    'price' => $products[$_POST['product']] * $_POST['quantity'],
    );  

print_r($_SESSION['list']) ;

//listing
echo  "<b>SHOPPING LIST</b></br>\n";

foreach($_SESSION as $key => $item) {
    echo $key, '. ', $item['item'], ' ', $item['quantity'], ' units ', $item['price']."\n";
}

echo "</br> <a href='index.html'>Return to index</a> </br>";

//Recycling list
$_SESSION['list'] = ''; 
//Printing session
print_r($_SESSION);

?>
```

That will print this result:

```
list. Banana 50 units 2500
```